# Is it possible to put layout xml's in subdirectories under /res/layout?

Tags: android

My layout files are growing and growing. So I came up with an idea of putting them in subdirectories. Is it possible? Simple code:

```
<include android:id="@+id/mLayout" layout="@layout/subdirectory/blahblah">
```

seem not to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is: no it isn't possible.

You can only make subfolders for different resolutions and screen sizes.

Comment: Ehhh, what a pity. Thanks anyway.