# Eclipse does not find new subfolders in res\

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-layout

I have the same problem discribed like here [Is it possible to put layout xml's in subdirectories under /res/layout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3387271/is-it-possible-to-put-layout-xmls-in-subdirectories-under-res-layout)

So i tried to make a subfolder in the res folder called layoutOptions. There i put some of my layout.xml files.
Then i tried to type `setContentView(R.layoutOtions.anyXmlFile);` but the compiler doesnt accept any folder except the normal layout and the drawable folder.

How can i "tell" eclipse, that there are some new subfolders in the resfolder which i want to take?

Or is there any other way to put my layout xmls in different folders?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is clearly written in the accepted answer of the question you linked to; You cannot make folders except for different resolutions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Same answer as in the linked question: you can't, it's not supported by the Android build tools. Best you can do is use a naming convention for your layouts, etc.

Comment: its not even possible to make a subfolder one folder section above...?
oh hell.
I thought the answer on the question i linked only counst for subfolders in the layout folder.
But thanks anyway.

Comment: Resources are grouped by type, and every type corresponds to  a particular folder name (or prefix). You can't have arbitrary names for resource folders.

Comment: Okay, thank you for your detailed answer.
But now i have another wierd problem. Eclipse doesnt find any .xml files except the main.xml in the res/layout folder.

Comment: @mkay: Clean or Refresh the project.

Comment: i dont know why, but right after i clicked "Clean" eclipse said my R.Java was deleted :/
And now i cant even choose the main.xm, only things like 
setContentView(R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
looks like i have to start all over again.

Comment: R.java is generated based on your resources, it's not a problem if it is deleted. Get the latest ADT version, set the project to 'Build automatically' and clean it once in a while if you get strange resource-related errors.

Comment: yeah i made a second mistake too...
I renamed the layouts with a prefix like optionsDeffault.xml .
Layout xmls mussnt have a big letter,but if you rename one ecplipse doesnt tell you. 
But thanks to you again.